# how to disable a log4j timestamp for only particular lines

Tags: java, log4j

i have logging configured in log4j.properties file , i am getting a output something like this

```
2013-11-12 19:33:17,897  - INFO Starting queue dispatching for DaphneStore Queue:  om.fi
2013-11-12 19:33:17,897  - INFO Starting CBR queue dispatching for DaphneStore
2013-11-12 19:33:17,897  - INFO Starting server shutdown
```

is there any possibility that i do not get timestamp information on the left hand side for some of the lines, something like this

```
2013-11-12 19:33:17,897  - INFO Starting queue dispatching for DaphneStore Queue: 
Starting CBR queue dispatching for DaphneStore
Starting server shutdown
```

here is my log4j configuration

```
# Set root logger to output only ERROR and FATAL events to R appender
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, R

# Define R appender to output to local log
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.file=D:/logs/abc.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of quick solutions:

- Create a **different appender with ConversionPattern=%m%n** (This will just print the logger text without timestamps I suppose).
- Modify the exisitng appender with ConversionPattern=%m%n. Here you can **manually add timestamps** (using DateFormat like SimpleDateFormat) to the logger text wherever needed. In rest of the cases, plain text will be added to the logger file without timestamp.

Comment: actually it is the other way round , i need timestamp in most of the lines and without timestamp only on few lines.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You just need to create one method one will append timestamp to the logger text. Call this method before writing the data to log file in most of your cases. Or else, go with the first approach which is more cleaner and loosely coupled.

Comment: right now it has ConversionPattern, log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n if i add another ConversionPattern where should i specify that for particular logs the new ConversionPattern should be used..

Comment: You need to configure a separate appender all together, add conversion pattern to it similar to log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern and direct the output of this appender to the same file. Now you can use this appender to added logger statements without timestamp info.

Comment: Ok, then in my code suppose i am adding logger.info("some message") , how will it identify whether it has to use which conversion pattern

Comment: Please read about log4J appenders in detail. You can create multiple logger instances pointing to different appenders. Use appropriate logger instances for adding or not adding timestamp value.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not using log4j correctly. Every call to `log.info/error/...()` is considered a separate log message.

What you are probably trying to do is something like this:

```
final StringBuilder logmsg = new StringBuilder();
logmsg.append("Starting queue dispatching for DaphneStore Queue: \n");
logmsg.append("Starting CBR queue dispatching for DaphneStore\n");
logmsg.append("Starting server shutdown\n");

log.info(logmsg);
```

**UPDATE**

What I mean is that the timestamp is an important part of a log message, it says **when** something happened. If you don't need this information *all the time* you should probably lose the timestamp all-together and put a single logging call to mark when your application was started:

```
String moment = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ...")).format(new Date());
log.info(moment + " Application started");
```